# DFP post-rendering callback

Tags: javascript, google-dfp

I need to trigger some JavaScript **after** DFP has finished rendering all the ads on the page - or at least when it has triggered *collapseEmptyDivs* (which hides ad units that contain no line items).

Is anyone aware of a way to get DFP to trigger a callback after either of these events?

Comment: Which direction did you end up going with this? Assuming the problem was that you were trying to prevent the flash of empty ad space caused by collapseEmptyDivs?

Comment: I found a solution to the problem I stated previously: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17931853/105061

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The GPT API now has a callback that is triggered after each slot is filled.

For example:

```
googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', function(event) {
 console.log('Creative with id: ' + event.creativeId +
  ' is rendered to slot of size: ' + event.size[0] + 'x' + event.size[1]);
});
```

See https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.events.SlotRenderEndedEvent

Comment: One thing to note, slotRenderEnded fires once the creative returned from DFP/AdX has been written into the page. If that creative has additional resources in it, they likely will not be rendered yet.

Comment: @mmilleruva or anyone is there a way to find out when all the creative has loaded? I'm guessing no but just looking for confirmation

Answer (score 20):

I hacked googletag's debug_log.log function and pushed it through jQuery to fire events on a lot of DFP's actions.  The hack does require jQuery.

https://github.com/mcountis/dfp-events

- gpt-google_js_loaded
- gpt-gpt_fetch
- gpt-gpt_fetched
- gpt-page_load_complete
- gpt-queue_start
- gpt-service_add_slot
- gpt-service_add_targeting
- gpt-service_collapse_containers_enable
- gpt-service_create
- gpt-service_single_request_mode_enable
- gpt-slot_create
- gpt-slot_add_targeting
- gpt-slot_fill
- gpt-slot_fetch
- gpt-slot_receiving
- gpt-slot_render_delay
- gpt-slot_rendering
- gpt-slot_rendered

Comment: The above implementation where you are checking if the ad does not exists by checking the children of the first iframe that is rendered might not work everytime. For e.g a 3rd party ad like sharethrough does not renders ad in iframe but as a simple div container. The above implementation would fail in that case.  Check here to see a sharethrough and see how it is rendered.http://imm.io/1kPqP

Comment: Nice code.  I wish there were some comments though explaining what exactly you are doing to get these to fire.  The code seems simple enough, but I don't fully understand where these ID numbers come in.  I assume that's just how they are compiled in DFP's minified output?  If so, how do you stay on top of changes?

Answer (score 9):

Load script in the  part of your page:

```js
// set global variable if not already set
var googletag = googletag || {};
googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];

// load asynchronously the GPT JavaScript library used by DFP,
// using SSL/HTTPS if necessary
(function() {
  var gads   = document.createElement('script');
  gads.async = true;
  gads.type  = 'text/javascript';

  var useSSL = 'https:' === document.location.protocol;
  gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
  var node =document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
})();
```

Initialise google publisher tag with the following script, preferable as well in the  section of your page:

```js
// can be moved as well in the body
// if using async mode, wrap all the javascript into googletag.cmd.push!
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
  // set page-level attributes for ad slots that serve AdSense
  googletag.pubads().set("adsense_background_color", "FFFFFF");
  googletag.pubads().setTargeting("topic","basketball");

  // enables Single Request Architecture (SRA)
  googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();

  // Disable initial load, we will use refresh() to fetch ads.
  // Calling this function means that display() calls just
  // register the slot as ready, but do not fetch ads for it.
  googletag.pubads().disableInitialLoad();

  // Collapses empty div elements on a page when there is no ad content to display.
  googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();

  // Enables all GPT services that have been defined for ad slots on the page.
  googletag.enableServices();
});
```

Register slots individually (can be generated with a foreach loop) and render them. The event listener can be registered as well per slot.
Here the important part: make sure that you refresh them together to avoid ending up with the same ads on both slots (if the ad is assign to both slots) => googletag.pubads().refresh([slot1, slot2]]);

```js
// this code can be moved externally to improve performance
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
  // define slot1
  slot1 = googletag.defineSlot(
    "/1234/travel/asia/food",
    [728, 90],
    "banner1"
  )
  .addService(googletag.pubads())
  .setTargeting(
    "interests",
    ["sports", "music", "movies"]
  );
  // prerender the slot but don't display it because of disableInitialLoad()
  googletag.display("banner1");

  // define slot2    
  slot2 = googletag.defineSlot(
    "/1234/travel/asia/food",
    [[468, 60], [728, 90], [300, 250]],
    "banner2"
  )
  .addService(googletag.pubads())
  .setTargeting("gender", "male")
  .setTargeting("age", "20-30");

  // prerender the slot but don't display it because of disableInitialLoad()
  googletag.display("banner2");  


  // add event to sign the slot as redered or not
  googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', function(event) {
    if (event.slot === slot1 || event.slot === slot2) {
      // do something related to the slot
    }
  });

  // refresh all container ads and show them
  // very important to call refresh with an array to avoid 
  // multiple callback to the registered event 
  googletag.pubads().refresh([slot1, slot2]);
});
```

```html
<div id="banner1" style="width:300px; height:250px;"></div>

<div id="banner2" style="width:300px; height:250px;"></div>
```

After the ad has been rendered, the callback gets triggered.

For more information have a look on this file:
https://github.com/davidecantoni/googletag

Comment: @kleopatra thank you for your feedback! I was in a hurry... shame on me :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that DFP doesn't provide for a callback after the ad has rendered. I have used the following code to do this. It calls the callback function after one of the following has happened:

-The ad has loaded and the iframe has rendered

-No ad was loaded, and the ad unit was hidden by collapseEmptyDivs()

-A certain amount of time has passed (in this case, 2 seconds) with neither one happening. 
Like if there was some sort of network error connecting to DFP.

adId would be the id of your ad container

assumes you are using jQuery

```
function callback() {
   //your callback function - do something here
}

function getIframeHtml(iframe) {
   if(iframe.contentWindow && iframe.contentWindow.document && iframe.contentWindow.document.body && iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML) {
       return iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
   }
   return null;
}

var dfpNumChecks = 20;
var dfpCheckCount = 0;
var dfpCheckTimer = 100;

function dfpLoadCheck(adId) {
   var nodes = document.getElementById(adId).childNodes;

   if(nodes.length && nodes[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'iframe' && getIframeHtml(nodes[0])) {
       //the iframe for the ad has rendered
       callback();
       return;
   } else if($('#' + adId).css('display') == 'none' || (dfpCheckCount >= dfpNumChecks)) {
       //the ad unit has been hidden by collapseEmptyDivs()
       callback();
       return;
   } else {
       dfpCheckCount++;
       setTimeout(function() { dfpLoadCheck(adId) }, dfpCheckTimer); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [jQuery DFP](https://github.com/coop182/jquery.dfp.js) extension I'm working on... it is still a bit of a work in progress but provides the callback you are after.

An example of how to use it is in [this file](https://github.com/coop182/jquery.dfp.js/blob/master/example-bootstrap.js).

You will see two callbacks are available... after each ad has loaded and after all ads have loaded. A class is also set on the ad unit container element, this can either be display-none (when no ad is found), display-block (when an ad is found) or display-original (for when no ad is found but the container div contained content to begin with, I use this for over riding certain parts of sites with ad content when required). These classes are of course useful to work with once inside the callback.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to identify the render end of a specific slot ( useful if you are using same creative for multiple slots ) you can do the following

```
googleAd =  googletag.defineSlot('/xxxxx/web_top_AAAxAAA', [xxx, xxx], 'div-id').addService(googletag.pubads());    


googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', function(event) {
                    if( event.slot.W == googleAd.W ){
                        // your code here
                    }
                });
```